# Heroku run rake db:reset error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am trying to reset my Heroku database. I am getting the following error:

```
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Object::State
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
/app/db/seeds.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:520:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:520:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib
```

Line 9 of seed.rb is State.create(name: 'Alaska', abbrev: 'AK' );
The model is defined.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rake db:reset task` is not supported. Heroku apps do not have permission to drop and create databases. Use the `heroku pg:reset` command instead.